# C++ reading a String character by character

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a constraint to read the input strings character by character. So I'm checking for `\n` after each string. But the program is not terminating.

Here's the problem I'm facing in a very short code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    while(cin >> c)
    {                
        char x;
        cin >> x;
        while(x != '\n')
        {       
            // print the characters
            cin >> x;  
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `c` will have the first character of the string while `x` will have the rest of characters one by one.

Input Case:

```
banananobano
abcdefhgijk
Radaradarada
```

Comment: Why are you using two `while` loops? Inner loop won't terminate since you are not changing `x` in it

Comment: By default, `cin >> c` (where `c` is a `char`) will skip all white space (including new-lines).

Comment: So can i read the white space or /n in some way or use some other input format ?

Comment: If you want to check for whitespaces then just check `c` directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a constraint to read the input strings character by character

One way of reading character by character, is via [`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

If you define

```
char c;
```

then

```
std::cin.get(c);
```

will read the next character into `c`.

In a loop, you could use it as

```
while(std::cin.get(c))
    <body>
```

Answer (score 6):

cin is whitespace delimited, so any whitespace (including \n) will be discarded. Thus, `x` will never be

Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) for reading line from the input stream and then use [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/) to get formatted input from the line.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
while ( iss >> c) {    
     print the characters;
  }
```